# Getting statistics for a channel with spaces in name

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

I am not able to get the channel's data if the channel name has spaces in it, e.g. `Meditation Relax Music`.

My API call :

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=Meditation+Relax+Music&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

My approach to get the data is, to remove spaces from the name before calling the API. It is working for some of the channels like `Unversal Pictures`

Test sample:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 dynamic var = client.DownloadString(@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=Meditation+Relax+Music&key={YOUR_API_KEY}");
```

Please help!

Comment: Could you post the relevant code, the lines which declare, initialize, and use the channel name? See [ask].

Comment: Here we go: WebClient client = new WebClient();
            dynamic var = client.DownloadString(@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=Meditation+Relax+Music&key={YOUR_API_KEY}");

Answer (score 2):

Try this, change the `forUsername` to `YourRelaxMusic1`, my api call:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=YourRelaxMusic1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The channel has a unique representation and this is the `id`, and the  owner of the channel is the `YourRelaxMusic1` user in this case. So if you dont have the id of the channel you need to get it through the username.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, I appreciated your point on this. I did the same, but now I have clarity on the same.

Comment: you welcome. if u believe my answer is correct accept it please. thanks